# Mean and Variance of Gaussian Process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $B = (B_t : t \geq 0)$ be a standard Brownian Motion. Fix $0 \leq s \leq t$.

How can I prove that, conditionally on $\{B_s = x, B_t = z\}$, the intermediate value $$B_{\frac{t+s}{2}}$$ has Gaussian distribution with mean $\left(\frac{x+z}{2}\right)$ and variance $\left(\frac{t-s}{4}\right)$ ?.

It looks like it is a bit more tricky than it actually seems at first sight.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We introduce the random variable

$$
Z=B_{(t+s)/2}+\frac{x+z}{2}-\frac12(B_t+B_s),
$$

Then, $Z$ is a Gaussian random variable since $(B_t)_{t\ge0}$ is a Gaussian process. Additionally, $Z$ is independent from $B_t$ and $B_s$ since $\mathbb E[ZB_s]=E[ZB_t]=0=E[Z]E[B_s]=E[Z]E[B_t]$. This implies that $Z$ has the same distribution as $B_{(t+s)/2}$ conditional on $B_t=x$ and $B_s=z$.

It remains to check that $E[Z]=\frac{x+z}{2}$ and 
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Var}\,{Z}&=E\left[\left(B_{(t+s)/2}-\frac12(B_t+B_s)\right)^2\right]\\
&=E\left[\left(B_{(t+s)/2}\right)^2\right]+\frac14E\left[B_t^2+B_s^2+2B_tB_s\right]-E\left[\left(B_{(t+s)/2}\right)(B_t+B_s)\right]\\
&=\frac{t+s}2+\frac14(t+s+2s)-\frac{t+s}2-s\\
&=\frac{t-s}{4}.
\end{align*}

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. Concerning the calculation of $VarZ$, are you using the expression $VarZ = E(Z - EZ)^2$. I am getting a slightly different result so I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @Adam, yes indeed. I added the details of the calculations to my post. Hope this clears things up.

Comment: I've been thinking about your answer, but I have doubt now: why can't we say that $E(B_{\frac{t+s}{2}}) = 0$? Isn't $B$ a Brownian Motion?

Comment: @Adam, indeed, $E\left(B_{\frac{t+s}2}\right)=0$. However, you want $E\left(B_{\frac{t+s}2}\,\big|\,B_s=x,B_t=z\right)$, which is nonzero. The whole point of introducing this $Z$ is to avoid this conditioning, and just study a regular random variable.

Comment: Why do the independence relations imply that it is a conditional distribution?