# conditional expectation of the Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

$(B_t)$ is a Brownian motion and i assume that $s<t<u$ we have $$E[B_t |\sigma(B_s,B_u)] = G(B_s,B_u)$$ Does anyone knows the explicit expression of $G$ ? (the calculus is easy but fastidious...). Thank you.

Comment: The question is not research-level.

Comment: Hint: the Brownian motion is a Gaussian process, so $\mathsf{E}[B_t \mid B_s, B_u]$ is a linear function of $(B_s, B_u)$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805820/conditional-expectation-of-brownian-motion