# Enlarging the filtration breaks the martingale property

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales, filtrations

Let $(W_t)_{t\in[0,1]}$ be a Brownian motion and let
$$\mathscr{G}_t = \sigma(W_1) \vee \sigma\left(W_s : s\in [0,t]\right), t \in [0,1]$$
Calculate $E[W_t|\mathscr{G_s}]$ for $0 \le s \le t \le 1$, and prove that the Brownian motion $(W_t)_{t\in[0,1]}$ is not a $\mathscr{G}$-martingale.

Intuitively, it makes perfect sense for me, since $\mathscr{G}_t$ contains not only the information prior to time $t$ but also the information about $W_1$. But I am struggling on how to write the proof explicitly. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What did you find for $E[W_t|\mathscr{G_s}]$?

Comment: @Did I tried $E[W_t|\mathscr{G}_s] =W_s + E[W_t - W_s|\mathscr{G}_s] = W_s + E[W_t - W_s|W_1]$$. Is this valid?

Comment: Actually, $E[W_t-W_s|\mathscr{G_s}]=E[W_t-W_s|W_s,W_1]$, not $E[W_t-W_s|W_s,W_1]$, but this requires a justification. Please explain why you think that $E[W_t-W_s|\mathscr{G_s}]=E[W_t-W_s|W_1]$.

Comment: @Did I think that $W_t - W_s$ is independent about the filtration $\sigma(W_s: s \in [0,t])$, so the only information relevant will be $\sigma(W_1)$. Sorry I am kind of new about this.

Comment: Your fallacy is to believe that if $X$ and $\mathcal G$ are independent then $E(X\mid\mathcal G,\sigma(Y))=E(X\mid Y)$ -- which is not true.

Comment: @Did Thanks a lot for pointing this out! Hmmm, will this be $E[W_t|\mathscr{G}_s] = W_s + E[W_t - W_s | W_1 - W_s]$? I do not know how to go any further.

Comment: Do you realize that you are saying you cannot compute $E(U\mid V)$ when $(U,V)$ is a centered gaussian vector with known covariance matrix? This seems like a prerequisite before tackling Brownian motion questions, no?

Comment: @Did Thanks!! Got the question now! Asked something stupid in the last post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to show that  $W$ is not a $\mathcal{G}$ martingale if you take $t=1$:
$$
E[W_1\mid\mathcal G_{0.5}] =W_1 \neq W_{0.5},
$$
so $W$ is not a $\mathcal{G}$ martingale.

Edit, changed the link:

To compute $E[W_t\mid\mathcal G_{s}]$ for general $0\leq s \leq t \leq 1$, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805820/conditional-expectation-of-brownian-motion) might help